# Incorrectly assigning a variable of custom type does not give an error in static type check

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am assigning a variable `stringFn` of type `Function(String)` like :

```dart
Function(String) stringFn = (String? s) {};
```

The dart static type checking does not give an error even though the `stringFn` is assigned a function that can receive a nullable parameter.

Printing the runtimeType of `stringFn` results in `(String?) => Null`  but if I call the function :

```dart
stringFn(null);
```

results in `The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'` which I agree because the type does not allow nullable parameter.

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intended behavior. `String?` can be thought of as a *more* generic type than `String` because it can accept all `String`s **and** `null`.

Therefore, any `String` passed to a `Function(String)` can be guaranteed to be handled properly by your `(String? s){}`. `stringFn` claims it can handle all non-null `String` values based on its variable type. `(String? s){}` knows how to handle all of those non-null `String`s *in addition* to `null`, so the code is valid.

You'll see that if you try to pass `null` to `stringFn`, you should get a *static analysis error*, not runtime:

```dart
void main() {
  Function(String) stringFn = (String? s) {};
  
  stringFn(null);//The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'
}
```

---

Attempting to do the reverse(flip the type and the assignment) will show a static analysis error on the `stringFn` line:

```dart
void main() {
  Function(String?) stringFn = (String s) {};//The argument type 'Null Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(String?)'
  
  stringFn(null);
}
```

This is again expected as your argument `(String s){}` does not know how to handle a nullable type as your variable's type implies it should. Based on the type of `stringFn`, `null` should be handled properly, but it wouldn't be able to do so with `(String s){}`.

Comment: I think I understood. So in this case there will be no difference between `Function(String) stringFn = (String? s){}` vs `Function(String) stringFn = (String s){}` during the function call because the former's more generic assignment is limited by the Type.

Comment: @CalvinGonsalves Yes, those would both be equivalent.